# Proper way to send data when using select() and write_fds in C

Tags: c, sockets, select

So I'm building a chat server, now I'm trying to echo all the messages from the client. Currently as soon as I get the message, I send it back within `readData()`. However, as soon as I send it, `select()` notifies the  `write_fds` and `sendData()` is called, even I already called `send()`

Most of my calls to send data would be inside the `readData()`.

- Is this the right way of using `select()` and `write_fds`?
- How can I notify `select()` that I want to send data without two calls to `send()`?

It seems redundant to me having to deal with two calls to `send()`.

```
int readData(int j){
    // get message from the client
    recv(j, client_buffer , 6000 , 0);
    // echo message to the client
    send(j, client_buffer, strlen(client_buffer));
}   
int sendData(int j){
    send(j, buf, nbytes, 0);
}   

for(;;){
    read_fds = master; 
    write_fds = master;
    if(select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL) == -1){
        exit(4);
    }   
    for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++){
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)){
            if(i == listener){
                // handle new connections
                addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
                newfd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);
                FD_SET(newfd, &master);
                if(newfd > fdmax) fdmax = newfd;
            }else{  
                // we got some data from a client
                readData(i); 
            }   
        }  
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &write_fds)){
            if(i != listener){
                // send data when notified
                sendData(i);
            }
        }    
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1) (assuming TCP here) send() and recv have a return value. use it. And deal with partial reads/writes. 2) you cannot use strlen() on the buffer after receiving, since it is not necessarily NUL-terminated. 3) a -1 return from send/recv/select is not always an error. It could be an interrupted system call, an EWOULDBLOCK, or even an out-of resource condition. 4) after the accept() you probably want to add the new_fd to the read fd_fds.

Comment: `TCP`, that's correct. Thanks for pointing out the `strlen()`. About the return value, so you are saying that, always there will be two calls to `send()` but I just need to keep track how much data the first call sent and send the  rest in the second or third call?

Comment: I just pointed out the obvious errors. IMHO there will never be a 2nd or 3rd call to send, since the new fd is not in the write fd_set, and neither in the read_set. (both are copies of the master set)

Comment: Fixed accept(). Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. Use the return values to calculate how far you are, and what needs to be done next. And please don't correct errors in th question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not suggest calling `sendData()` directly inside of `readData()`. They should be kept separate. Have `readData()` return the received data to the caller, and let the caller decide what to do with it. If the caller wants to send data, it can then call `sendData()` as needed.

To address the `select()` issue, you need to create a per-socket buffer for outgoing data. And make sure the socket is running in non-blocking mode.

1. If `sendData()` is called when the buffer is empty, `send()` as much of the caller's data as possible. `send()` will return how many bytes it actually accepted. If `send()` reports a `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN` error, stop sending and append any unsent data to the end of the buffer.
2. If `sendData()` is called when the buffer is not empty, just append the new data to the end of the buffer and exit without calling `send()` at all.

Whenever `select()` reports a socket is writable, `send()` whatever is currently cached in that socket's buffer, if anything. For each successful `send()`, remove the reported number of bytes from the front of the buffer. Stop sending if the buffer is exhausted or `send()` fails.

Comment: Thanks, make sense now. BTW, do you know what would be a good size buffer for outgoing data, e.g., BUFSIZ? Or should it be dynamic, and keep re-sizing it i.e., `realloc`? I'm curious about what is the common practice on this.

Comment: @PeteDarrow the outgoing buffer shoukd be dynamic, since you don't know how much data will end up needing to be cached, but you can grow/reallocate it in sensible increments as needed. For instance, in 1kb increments. Or maybe in delta amounts, like 256 bytes, then 512 bytes, then 1kb, etc. Or rounded up to even multiples of a decent value. It really depends on how much data you will be sending. Try to reallocate it as few times as possible, but reuse it as much as possible.